# Accessing Multiple Entity Values in a Join Query Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I have an application that essentially has Post/Comment-like functionality. I need the application to render a Post index page from the Post entity with the latest comment and author being displayed from the Comment entity.

My database/table structure is (ids are primary just not shown as such) and sample data:

```
create table post
(
    id    int auto_increment,
    title text not null,
    constraint post_id_uindex
        unique (id)
);

id,title
1,This is test post number 1
4,This is test post number 2
5,This is test post number 3

create table comment
(
    id         int auto_increment,
    comment    text     null,
    author     text     null,
    created_at datetime null,
    post_id    int      null,
    constraint comment_id_uindex
        unique (id),
    constraint comment_post_id_fk
        foreign key (post_id) references post (id)
);

id,comment,author,created_at,post_id
1,Nice Post this is,Stephen,2021-08-03 16:49:22,1
2,Another nice post,Billy,2021-08-03 16:49:44,1
3,I didn't like the post at all,Karen,2021-08-04 10:57:05,1
```

I have bi-directional mapping set up in my two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    private int id;
    private String comment;
    private String author;
    private Timestamp createdAt;
    private Post postByPostId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "comment")
    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "author")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Timestamp createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Comment comment1 = (Comment) o;
        return id == comment1.id && Objects.equals(comment, comment1.comment) && Objects.equals(author, comment1.author) && Objects.equals(createdAt, comment1.createdAt);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, comment, author, createdAt);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Post getPostByPostId() {
        return postByPostId;
    }

    public void setPostByPostId(Post postByPostId) {
        this.postByPostId = postByPostId;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Post {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private Collection<Comment> commentsById;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Post post = (Post) o;
        return id == post.id && Objects.equals(title, post.title);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, title);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postByPostId")
    public Collection<Comment> getCommentsById() {
        return commentsById;
    }

    public void setCommentsById(Collection<Comment> commentsById) {
        this.commentsById = commentsById;
    }
}
```

The PostRepository @Query I am using is below. The query itself works as raw SQL and I get the post with those latest comment data:

```
id,title,id,comment,author,created_at,post_id
1,This is test post number 1,3,I didn't like the post at all,Karen,2021-08-04 10:57:05,1
4,This is test post number 2,,,,,
5,This is test post number 3,,,,,
```

But when I try accessing the comment fields in my Thymeleaf template using ${post.commentsById} all comments are being displayed which I was hoping would only display the one comment object joined from the @Query command. I also see that when I remove the @Query it does the same thing making the @Query pointless in this case.

Can anyone give me direction on how to correctly set this us? Thanks in advance.

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select p.*, c.* from post p left join (select a.* from comment a join (select max(created_at) created_at from comment group by post_id) b on a.created_at = b.created_at) c on p.id = c.post_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Post> findAll();
}
```

post.html Thymeleaf template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="text-center m-5">
        <h1 class="display-6">Posts
            <small class="text-muted" th:text="${title}"></small>
        </h1>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Post ID</th>
            <th>Post Title</th>
            <th>Latest Comment ID</th>
            <th>Latest Comment</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="post : ${posts}">
            <td th:text="${post.getId} ?: '-'">-</td>
            <td th:text="${post.title} ?: '-'">-</td>
            <td th:text="${post.commentsById} ?: '-'"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Rendered HTML with Comment object array instead of latest comment from @Query

```
Post ID Post Title  Latest Comment ID   Latest Comment  Author  Created At
1   This is test post number 1  [com.example.demo.entity.Comment@6d578e15, com.example.demo.entity.Comment@e74e80e, com.example.demo.entity.Comment@42b0db5]
4   This is test post number 2  []
5   This is test post number 3  []
```

Comment: My suspicion is output of native query `select p.*, c.* from post p left...` is not able to bind correctly to fields of Post entity. Can you try giving exact alias as field names of Post entity, or use spring data projections https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions?

Answer (score 1):

I took Hopey One's advice and renamed my query which is probably best practice to leave default query names alone. Projections suggested by Ashutosh did work.

I created an Interface for the index page:

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public interface Index {

    int getPostId();

    String getPostTitle();

    String getLatestComment();

    String getLatestCommentAuthor();

    Timestamp getLatestCommentCreatedAt();
}
```

In the PostRepository I created the @Query giving aliases to the fields in the Index interface:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select p.id as postId, p.title as postTitle, c.comment as latestComment, c.author as latestCommentAuthor, c.created_at as latestCommentCreatedAt from post p left join (select a.* from comment a join (select max(created_at) created_at from comment group by post_id) b on a.created_at = b.created_at) c on p.id = c.post_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Index> findAllWithLatestComment();
}
```

My Thymeleaf code snippet

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Post ID</th>
        <th>Post Title</th>
        <th>Latest Comment</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="post : ${posts}">
        <td th:text="${post.postId} ?: '-'">-</td>
        <td th:text="${post.postTitle} ?: '-'">-</td>
        <td th:text="${post.latestComment} ?: '-'">-</td>
        <td th:text="${post.latestCommentAuthor} ?: '-'">-</td>
        <td th:text="${post.latestCommentCreatedAt} ?: '-'">-</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML Output

```
Posts All Posts
Post ID Post Title  Latest Comment  Author  Created At
1   This is test post #1    I didn't like the post at all   Karen   2021-08-04 10:57:05.0
6   This is test post #2    -   -   -
```

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

`JpaRepository` already defines `findAll` as the method that will find all entities. I'm not sure what the effect of declaring/over-riding it in your repository annotated with `@Query` will be. You could turn on the SQL debugging in JPA to find out exactly what is executing. It might be worth renaming your `findAll` method and calling the new method name to see if that works.

However I think there is probably a better alternative, like adding a getter method to return the latest comment in your entity and calling that in your template.